# Создание листа содержащего ссылки на свойство c#

Tags: c#, ref

Есть класс `Rights` содержащий свойство `Title` доступное на чтение и запись. Мне Необходимо в список `List<string> RightsList` записать ссылки на элементы на свойство `Title`. Пробую добавить в класс  `Rights` следующий метод

```
public ref string GetTitleLink()
{
    return ref Title;
}
```

Соответственно ловлю ошибку. Подскажите, как это сделать грамотно.

Answer (score 0):

Но зачем вам ссылка на свойство класса - вы собираетесь потом обращаться к свойству класса "через голову" самого класса, содержащего это свойство? Это противоречит принципу инкапсуляции. Если свойство класса может поменяться, то лучше хранить ссылку на сам этот класс и обращаться к этому классу за актуальным значением его свойства.

Comment: Решаю проблемы вывода Title списком, сейчас выводятся девером, и работает кучу event. мне нельзя менять никакую логику, а только изменить визуальное отображение, для этого мне необходимы ссылки на Title